# Invalid property 'redeemVoucherForm' of bean class [my.testapp.forms.RedeemVoucherForm]

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm getting an error:

```
Invalid property 'redeemVoucherForm' of bean class [my.testapp.forms.RedeemVoucherForm]: Bean property 'redeemVoucherForm' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

RedeemVoucherForm.java:

```
package my.testapp.forms;

public class RedeemVoucherForm {

    private String voucherCode;

    public String getVoucherCode() {
        return voucherCode;
    }

    public void setVoucherCode(String voucherCode) {
        this.voucherCode = voucherCode;
    }
}
```

In my `PageController.java`, I'm adding model `redeemVoucherForm`, which exist, when I call method model.containsAttribute("redeemVoucherForm"):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showPage(final Model model) {
    ...
    model.addAttribute("redeemVoucherForm", new RedeemVoucherForm());
    ...
    return REDIRECT_PAGE_URL;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/redeem-voucher", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String redeemVoucher(@Valid final RedeemVoucherForm redeemVoucherForm, final BindingResult bindingResult, final RedirectAttributes redirectModel, final Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    LOG.debug("<POST> Redeeming voucher...");

    return REDIRECT_PAGE_URL;
}
```

pageDisplay.jsp:

```
<c:url value="/page/redeem-voucher" var="redeemVoucherAction" />
<form:form action="${redeemVoucherAction}" method="post" commandName="redeemVoucherForm">
        <form:input cssClass="form-control" type="text" path="redeemVoucherForm.voucherCode"/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block checkoutButton">
            <spring:theme text="Redeem Voucher"/>
        </button>
</form:form>
```

What else could I be missing, when I have set model `redeemVoucherForm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this line

```xml
    <form:input cssClass="form-control" type="text" path="redeemVoucherForm.voucherCode"/>
```

should be

```xml
    <form:input cssClass="form-control" type="text" path="voucherCode"/>
```

The `path` element of a `<form:input>` should be relative to the object you've set as the `commandName` of your `<form:form>`.  In your case, this object is an instance of your class `RedeemVoucherForm`.

If you set the path to `redeemVoucherForm.voucherCode`, Spring looks for a `redeemVoucherForm` property on your class `RedeemVoucherForm`.  It expects the value of this to be some object with a `voucherCode` property, from which it can read the form value.  Of course, the `redeemVoucherForm` property doesn't exist, hence you get the error.

Comment: `redeemCode`?  That must be in your code somewhere but it doesn't appear anywhere in the code you've posted.

Comment: My bad, I typed wrong again. Instead of voucherCode, I wrote redeemCode. Everything is ok. Thank you very much for that!